# Vector iterator incompatible ? Same vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code

```
 vector<Interval> insert(vector<Interval>& intervals, Interval newInterval) 
    {
        vector<Interval> res;
        vector<Interval>::iterator it;
        for (it = intervals.begin(); it != intervals.end(); it++) 
        {
            if (newInterval.start < (*it).start) 
            {
                intervals.insert(it, newInterval);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (it == intervals.end())  //---->vector iterator incompatible
        {
            intervals.insert(it, newInterval); 
        }
}
```

I am getting an error of vector iterator incompatible at the statement

```
    if (it == intervals.end())  //---->vector iterator incompatible
    {
        intervals.insert(it, newInterval); 
    }
```

Can anyone please clarify why this is happening and how I can fix this ?
Also this happens even when insert is not called. This is the error that i get
[image]

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert Insert returns an iterator that you should use since it can invalidate existing ones if insertion causes a reallocation.

Comment: You can replace your function with `std::find_if` followed by a call to `insert`.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @RetiredNinja makes sense however this still happens even when insert is not called

Comment: Notice that the `insert` call inside the loop is the exact same as the one you're having to disable outside the loop.  You could just always call `insert` outside the loop, and make the loop responsible for finding the insertion point, not for doing an insertion.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, you just compared for inequality 8 lines above. The error must be coming from another line.

Comment: @alfC Not when `break;` was hit.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I am talking about compilation. Now I realize that this is a runtime error probably, some kind of "safe"/checked STL. In that case, yes, it must be a logic error.

Comment: There are only two ways to break out of the loop.  The first is `!(it != intervals.end())` which obviously didn't generate an error.  The second is the `break` after the `insert`, which we know is likely to invalidate `it` and generate the error.  Insisting that you get the error even in the first case simply doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @JamesFranco Your `insert` function invokes undefined behavior, since you failed to return a `vector<Interval>`.  Returning nothing from a function that is supposed to return something is undefined behavior.  If this is your real code, then there is no need to try and makes sense of the error you're seeing.  The program (and even the compiler) can do whatever it wants with what you've written.

Comment: Not to pour salt on the wound, but `res` and the declared return value both seem completely pointless here. The latter is especially damaging as Paul notes, since the caller assumes a vector by value is coming back, and you never both fulfilling that promise. And I'm pretty sure this entire thing could be done in two lines of code, especially if the precondition is that `intervals` is always sorted on the `start` member of it's inhabitants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator is invalidated with `insert`(For vector, an insertion may cause the memory reallocation, all elements are moved to a new address. The iterator is just a pointer, so it can't be used to compare with the new end of a vector, it's meaningless), as the comment mentioned, you need to reassign the return value to the `it` value. Or just simplified the code with `std::find_if`, it's preferred to use STL algorithms over hand write loop. To make code clear and more maintainable.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

vector<Interval> insert(vector<Interval>& intervals, Interval newInterval) {
  vector<Interval> res;
  if (auto itr = std::find_if(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(),
                              [&newInterval](const Interval& val) {
                                return newInterval.start < val.start;
                              });
      itr != intervals.end()) {
    intervals.insert(itr, std::move(newInterval));
  } else {
    intervals.push_back(std::move(newInterval));
  }
  // omitted
  return res;
}
```

Or just simplify as:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
vector<Interval> insert2(vector<Interval>& intervals, Interval newInterval) {
  vector<Interval> res;
  auto itr = std::find_if(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(),
                          [&newInterval](const Interval& val) {
                            return newInterval.start < val.start;
                          });
  intervals.insert(itr, std::move(newInterval));

  // omitted
  return res;
}
```

Comment: please don't declare variables inside an `if` condition :(

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you please elaborate on it? I think it's a handy feature from C++17, define a variable in `if` and check it immediately.

Comment: Its super useful when you need to limit the scope of the variable, such as with scoped locks, structured bindings, unique_ptr, etc.  The tradeoff is that it makes the code harder to read. In your case, you don't need the limited scope, so it's harder to read for no benefit.

Comment: @MooingDuck I intend to limit its scope, it's a short life variable. Then I can define the variable `itr` again in the code after this scope without getting a redefinition compile error.  I think it will improve the code readability, we don't need to look ahead many lines to find where the variable is defined.